# Why this es6-module export is not working/recognized?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I'm getting mad with module import/export syntax...

Say on a file I want to import a module like this:

```
import { AccordionMenu } from '../node_modules/lr-js-modules/accordion-menu';
```

Now, how should I export from accordion-menu? My current code is an old school js class like this:

```
AccordionMenu = function(options){
[...]
}

AccordionMenu.prototype = { ... }
```

Then I was exporting like this:

```
export { AccordionMenu as default };
```

It doesn't work. Compiler says

*export 'AccordionMenu' (imported as 'AccordionMenu') was not found in '../node_modules/lr-js-modules/accordion-menu' (possible exports: default)*

I then tried several variants, but none worked to me. From mdn docs, as far as I can tell, all teh variants should work, but it's evident that I'm doing something wrong.

Can you help please?

Comment: did you try `export { AccordionMenu }`?

Comment: Try this: `const AccordionMenu = function(options) { ... };` then at the end of the file `export default AccordionMenu;`. To import you can then `import AccordionMenu from '...';` - you don't need `{ ... }` as it's the default export

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is quite clear: you exported `default` but your import tries to access an export `AccordionMenu`.

You should use either

```
export function AccordionMenu(options) { … }
// same as:
// function AccordionMenu(options) { … }
// export { AccordionMenu as AccordionMenu }

AccordionMenu.prototype = { … };
```

with

```
import { AccordionMenu } from '../node_modules/lr-js-modules/accordion-menu';
// same as:
// import { AccordionMenu as AccordionMenu } from '../node_modules/lr-js-modules/accordion-menu';
```

**or**, if that function is the only (or main) export of that module, use a default export

```
export default function AccordionMenu(options) { … }
// same as:
// function AccordionMenu(options) { … }
// export { AccordionMenu as default }

AccordionMenu.prototype = { … };
```

with

```
import AccordionMenu from '../node_modules/lr-js-modules/accordion-menu';
// same as:
// import { default as AccordionMenu } from '../node_modules/lr-js-modules/accordion-menu';
```

but the mix doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you, the first solution is what I was looking for. It's quite comic that I'm programming es6 since at least 1 year and still I didn't fully understand import/export syntax, and above all, the reason under every variant. Still didn't find a really clear (to me) online documentation. I don't even fully get the reason why there are so many ways of doing this kind of things.